# python strftime without leading 0

Tags: python, strftime

It worked in last 20 days where i had two numbers in day

Now :

```
time data 'Jun  1 2020 12:00AM' does not match format '%B %d %Y %I:%M%p'
```

So the code which goes like

```
 #last_run_db = 'Jun  1 2020 12:00AM'
 last_run_date = datetime.strptime(last_run_db, "%B %d %Y %I:%M%p")
```

I tried with

```
  %-d
  %e
  %#d
```

Comment: -d is what you want, but it doesn't work on windows machines

Comment: do we have any replacement for it on Windows ? Or i maybe should on writing values into db set different format ?

Comment: @Chris I don't see anything about `%-d`, or about using either `-` or `#` in this way at all. I've only heard of using `-` to match literal `-` in the input.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel On Unix/Linux machines it will return the non-zero padded day, same for -m

Comment: Ah, but here we're *parsing* the date, not *formatting* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to leading 0 in the `%d`, but is due to the abbreviated month.

Use `%b` (for `"Jun"`), not `%B` (for `"June"`).

Comment: Because the previous month was May and it could be read using either %B or %b :)

Answer (score 0):

> It worked in last 20 days where i had two numbers in day

Another interesting thing about the last 20 days is that they were in May, where the full name of the month fits in three letters. `%B` is for the full name of the month; you want `%b` for this three-letter abbreviation. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).